# Flex "Debug Only" Code?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, actionscript, compiler-construction

Is there a way to mark certain parts of code so that they don't even get compiled in release mode? I know you can do it in C# with syntax like this:

```
if #DEBUG
    trace("Debug");
else
    trace("Release");
```

Does Actionscript/Flex have any similar feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
CONFIG::debugging { 
    trace("Debug"); 
}
CONFIG::release { 
    trace("Release"); 
}
```

using the following compiler arguments:

```
-define+=CONFIG::debugging,true -define+=CONFIG::release,false
```

More details is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html).